# codeception тестирование REST API загрузка файлов

Tags: php, api, rest, codeception

Подскажите, тестирую Api на codeception.Мне нужно протестировать метод загружающий файл методом POST. Документация скудновата по этому вопросу. Сам файл положил в _data.
тест не срабатывает(хотя должен). Подскажите в чем может быть ошибка

---

```
public function saveIdentificationPhotos(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $url = '/account/update-identification-photos';            
        $data = [
            'idDocument' => [
                'name' => 'test_image.jpg',
                'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                'error' => UPLOAD_ERR_OK,
                'size' => filesize(codecept_data_dir('test_image.jpg')),
                'tmp_name' => codecept_data_dir('test_image.jpg'),
            ],
            'idDocumentBack' => [
                'name' => 'test_image2.jpg',
                'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                'error' => UPLOAD_ERR_OK,
                'size' => filesize(codecept_data_dir('test_image2.jpg')),
                'tmp_name' => codecept_data_dir('test_image2.jpg'),
            ],
            'proofOfResidence' => [
                'name' => 'test_image3.jpg',
                'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                'error' => UPLOAD_ERR_OK,
                'size' => filesize(codecept_data_dir('test_image3.jpg')),
                'tmp_name' => codecept_data_dir('test_image3.jpg'),
            ],
            'csrf_token' => $I->getToken(),
        ];
        $I->sendPOST($url,  $data);            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод sendPost **третьим** параметром принимает массив файлов, вторым массив параметров.

```
public function sendPOST($url, $params = [], $files = [])
```

То есть у вас должно получится так:

```
$I->sendPOST('/account/update-identification-photos', [], [
    'photo' => [
        'name' => 'test_image.jpg',
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'error' => UPLOAD_ERR_OK,
        'size' => filesize(codecept_data_dir('test_image.jpg')),
        'tmp_name' => codecept_data_dir('test_image.jpg'),
    ],
]);
```

Comment: согласен, но как проверить, что файл пришел?какой assert использовать?или просто статус код на 200 проверить достаточно?

Comment: Если вы тестируете api, то нужно проверить, что api вернуло success ответ. Тут зависит от обработки на сервере.